# CSS files included with menu and PHP GET CSS selector

Tags: php, html, css, security, themes

I need visitors to change theme colors and background with a simple drop down menu theme selector. The select menu will send the form to index.php with a GET string ?theme=choice and PHP will take this GET and convert it to the site's css theme. I have 5 different CSS files (themes).

The select menu is done, but now I need PHP to handle the form in a correct and safe way. I do not know if Cookies are a good way but many says cookies are not a good idea so my idea is to maybe just add the ECHO theme and GET theme to all pages.

Here is what I have but is not working. I do not know how to make it better any ideas and help are welcome.

```
<head>
<?php
$theme = $_GET['theme'];
$security = mysqli_real_escape_string($theme); 
//don't know if needed because database will not be used for this

$onlynumbersandletters = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $security);
//allow only letters and numbers for more safety is needed ? 
// No database used but can someone hack a GET for this like in MySQL ?

//CODE
if(!empty($_GET['theme'])){
     echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/default.css" />';
}

else {
     echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/$onlynumbersandletters.css" />';
}

?>
<!-- other elements in head -->
</head>
```

I am new to PHP, the code I don't know if it is safe or can be improved but I dont get the correct theme when changing from select menu.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Printing variable into string works only if the string is in double quotes. Your is in single hence $onlynumbersandletters wont print out. It should look like this: `echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/'.$onlynumbersandletters.'.css" />';`

Cookies to store this are fine. And for your security concerns. If you plan to use that variable only for choosing css there is not much harm that can be done by attacker. But if you must, you could check if $theme is same as one of your css files and if not then show default template.

```
$dirty = isset($_GET['theme']) ? $_GET['theme'] : 'default';
$theme = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $dirty);
if (file_exists("./css/" . $theme . ".css")) {
    echo '<link rel"stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/'.$filename.'.css" />';
} else {
    // what to do if file is not on disk?
}
```

The regex replace is there for removing slashes to prevent finding out what css files are on server outside the ./css directory.

Comment: Good point. I missed the print thing. About security how to check is theme is the same? Maybe with arrays like when including pages ? like this $themes = array('theme1', 'theme2', 'theme3'); the problem is I don't know how to do it

Comment: Nice. The problem is what is the rest of the code... I am new to this. Sorry. In your code I see if GET string exist show but what happens when string is empty or the name is incorrect?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about that. Anyway I already show you reasonably good solution and you should fix details by yourself.

Comment: So looking at the code I understand the code will do the follow: If get empty string theme system will show theme "default" if real existing theme name1 it will show theme name1 if get non existing theme FAke1 system will show theme default?